# Docker-compose build error build path Testdriven.io tutorial

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following a tutorial from testdriven.io and I am stuck at the very beginning of setting up docker.

I can't understand why am I getting this error message and I hope someone can point me in right direction to find the error.

My dockerfile:

```
    # pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.2-alpine

# set work directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  movies:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env.dev
```

Error that I am receiving:

```
ERROR: build path /home/{user}/dev/django-tdd-docker/app/app either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

I don't know why does it append extra "app" at the end and I don't know where to remove it or if that will solve the problem. Hopefully this is enough information for the question, first time asking and I am first time poking around docker and docker-compose. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Could you show the project's structure? Meaning, where `docker-compose` file is located and where `Dockerfile` is located ?

Comment: As soon as I read the project's structure, it hit me. It was the problem that I have created dockerfile and docker-compose in the wrong folder. Thank you!